# Can I legally get SIM card in Germany as a tourist?

Tags: europe, germany, cellphones

This late July I went to EU for a 10 day trip. I live in the US. When I stopped at TMobile (or was it Deutsche Telekom?) store at Hamburg to buy a local SIM card. I was told that this is impossible, as SIM cards are sold to EU residents only according to the new law passed July,1st. As I am not a resident of EU they can not sell me even a prepaid card.

Questions: is this information correct? If it is, what options do we, regular tourists, have in Germany?

I was not able to confirm that by doing an online search. So if it is not true, what could have been the motives of the sales rep to deny the sale, and how can I get back at him.

Comment: There's some info [on this wiki here](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Germany), which certainly suggests that there is new legislation in Germany that took effect from July. It does suggest, however, that residence is not a strict requirement, and that the other carriers are less insistent that the address given has anything to do with you.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I was searching for a wrong keywords. Post it as an answer, and I will upvote.

Comment: Semi-relevant news post in German about the ALDI discounter having trouble identifying certain ID documents for SIM card registration: https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Verbraucherschuetzer-Aldi-sperrt-Fluechtlinge-bei-Mobilfunkangebot-aus-3814434.html

Answer (score 8):

Yes, but it depends what do you mean for ***getting a SIM card***...

if you are in Germany as a resident or tourist you can go to electronic stores like Saturn and find SIM card for like 5€, many Phone operators will even send you one for free per mail-post (e.g. O2), then after that you need to top on a little amount of money and there you are!

what the new law means is that **you can not buy that anonymously anymore** (for security reasons)

I quote the [news](https://www.pcwelt.de/a/registrierungspflicht-fuer-prepaid-sim-karten-das-muessen-sie-beachten,3447252):

> Am Samstag, dem 1. Juli 2017, tritt die Registrierungspflicht für
>   Prepaid-SIM-Karten in Deutschland in Kraft. Der Kauf einer
>   Prepaid-SIM-Karte mit einem Pseudonym ist dann nicht mehr möglich.
>   Kunden, die sich am morgigen Samstag eine neue Prepaid-SIM-Karte im
>   Supermarkt oder Mobilfunk-Geschäft kaufen, müssen ihren Namen, ihre
>   Adresse und ihr Geburtsdatum nachweisen.

the translation main idea is:

> since sat. Jul 1st 2017 you can buy a SIM card, but you have to give
>   your Name, Address and Birthday

so you still can show your id as tourist :) ...

---

Edit: if you still are interested in the law regulation see the [Paragraf 111 des Telekommunikationsgesetzes (TKG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/tkg_2004/__111.html)

Comment: As the link in waiwai933’s comment shows, it is considerably harder in practice than in theory. Your answer only covers the theoretical situation.

Comment: This is all amusing and relevant, but unfortunately, this is not an answer to the entire question I asked (the "what options" part)

Comment: As a tourist your only option is to show your id

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ which clearly did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

You can buy all the SIM cards you want, but can't activate them. You have to be registered in the German residence bureau's data base. No residency, no activation.

I went to Greece to get a SIM card.

Comment: Can you add some background information supporting that claim?